# Assign column names in string to dataframe - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following string in Python (is not a list, is a string):

```
a = ['cc_call_center_sk', 'cc_call_center_id', 'cc_rec_start_date', 'cc_rec_end_date']
```

I also have the following dataframe:

```
   0      1      2      3
0  AA     AB     BC     CD
1  AZ     ZR     RT     TN
```

What I want to do is to assign the string 'a' to the columns of the dataframe. I did this:

```
df.columns = a
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 
"['cc_call_center_sk', 'cc_call_center_id', 'cc_rec_start_date', 
'cc_rec_end_date']" was passed
```

I cannot pass directly the string to the df.columns. Any ideas on this? Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need convert strings to list by `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

df.columns = ast.literal_eval(a)
```

Another solution with `strip` and `split`, last remove `'` for each column name:

```
a = "['cc_call_center_sk', 'cc_call_center_id', 'cc_rec_start_date', 'cc_rec_end_date']"

#solution 1
df.columns = [x.strip("'") for x in a.strip("[]").split(', ')]
#solution 2
df.columns = pd.Index(a.strip('[]').split(', ')).str.strip("'")
```

---

```
print (df)
  cc_call_center_sk cc_call_center_id cc_rec_start_date cc_rec_end_date
0                AA                AB                BC              CD
1                AZ                ZR                RT              TN
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks @jezrael

Comment: @GabrielaMartinez - You are welcome! I notice first my answer was accepted and then remove accepting, so only ask if it was by accident or not - now is possible accept only one answer, not multiple. And which answer you choose it is up to you ;)

Comment: Sorry about that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Or even better, use `split`:

```
df.columns = map(lambda x:x[1:-1],a[1:-1].split(', '))
```

Then now:

```
print(df)
```

Will be desired output, like:

```
  cc_call_center_sk cc_call_center_id cc_rec_start_date cc_rec_end_date
0                AA                AB                BC              CD
1                AZ                ZR                RT              TN
```